# Lego sealed bags 135149 - year 2017

Tags: set-identification

I have 4 lego sealed bags with the number 135149 on it, from the year 2017.

Could someone help me find the instructions?

1 bag blue and green parts
1 bag yellow, orange and white parts
1 bag brown, black and grey parts
1 bag red and pink parts

Comment: Please add pictures.